# MacTeX 2019 vs. 2020: No more lmodern b, only lmodern bx?

Tags: pdftex, texlive-2019, lmodern, texlive-2020

The font "Latin Modern" comes with two different bold faces, one called "bold", the other one called "bold extended". Bold extended is the default for this font. With MacTeX 2020 as opposed to MacTeX 2019, I can't get the regular bold font of Latin Modern to work. See this minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{b}

\begin{document}

This is sample text \textbf{This is sample text}

\end{document}
```

Using MacTeX 2019, this produces the (correct) output

[image: Latin Modern Bold]

using MacTeX 2020, I get the output

[image]

Is this a known issue? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/306 seems relevant. The fix suggested there in the first comment seems to make `\DeclareFontSeriesDefault{bf}{b}` and `\DeclareFontSeriesDefault{bf}{bx}` work again.

Comment: @moewe Using \DeclareFontSeriesDefault{bf}{b} unfortunately does not solve the issue for me. I will have a closer look at the thread though, thanks

Comment: @moewe Using "\DeclareFonrSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}" as suggested in the mwe in the linked thread resolves the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The command `\bfdefault`is deprecated. Using

```
\DeclareFontSeriesDefault[rm]{bf}{b}
```

resolves the issue -- at least in this case.